# Code doesn't work on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone

This code works on desktop but not iPhone. I am new to javascript and trying to help out with fixing this issue. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery(function () {
            jQuery(".monthly-table").hide();
            jQuery("#show-monthly, #show-annual").bind("click", function () {
                jQuery(".monthly-table, .annual-table").hide();
                if (jQuery(this).attr("id") == "show-monthly")
                {
                    jQuery(".monthly-table").show();
                } else
                {
                    jQuery(".annual-table").show();
                }
            });
        });

    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.toggler-pricing a').on('click', function () {
            jQuery('.toggler-pricing a').removeClass('active');
            jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what exactly does not work?

Comment: What part of it doesn't work? The clicks? What is the expected behaviour? Can you post some HTML code?

Comment: Sorry, the click is not working. It is meant to toggle between 2 different tables on a WP site.

Comment: The page it is from is https://insuresign.com/sign-up-prices/ , Clicking on Monthly and Annual, works great on desktop but not at all on iOS.